# Damage dealt by creatures and the order of damage

Tags: magic-the-gathering

So I had an interesting one recently at our local win a box tournament.

Scene - I have 12 life remaining, my opponent has 9. I have an un-monstrous [Arbor Colossus](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Arbor%20Colossus) and a [Polukranos, World Eater](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Polukranos%2C%20World%20Eater)(monstrous 4), my opponent has no board at all apart from lands.

It's my turn, I attack with both my creatures. My opponent casts [Titan Strength](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Titan%20Strength) on my Polukranos and then casts [Deflecting Palm](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Deflecting%20Palm) on Polukranos so I am now dead to my own Polukranos (12/12).

The game ended here because my opponent started shouting so loud about how he had won with such a play that I missed a vital part of the board.

I could have used the monstrous ability on my Arbor Collosus and made that a 9/9. So I have this question:-

If I had used my monstrous on the Arbor Collosus - would that make the game a draw (we both die at the same time) or could I have had my creatures deal their damage in an order of my choosing, and thus win the game before being killed by my own Polukranos??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All combat damage is dealt at the same time, so yes, it would have been a draw.

Deflecting Palm is a replacement effect (instead of your opponent, you take damage the moment combat damage is dealt). This happens at the same time for all combat damage. So, the Polukranos damage hits you the same time the Arbor Colossus damage would have hit your opponent.

/edit: last paragraph was incorrect

Comment: And (for the last sentence of his question) it wouldn't have mattered if he could decide the order in which damage was dealt, because the players only actually lose the game the next time state based actions are checked. Right?

Comment: This was game 2, the final game ended in a draw for a draw overall. I had won the first game.

Comment: Regarding your final point: matches are played until time runs out or a player has won 2 games. If there is still time left and the current game score is 1 win for either or both players and any number of draws, the players should begin another game.

Comment: This is cool to know.  Do you have a reference for the "If damage is prevented this way, then do X" ability being a replacement effect and not a triggered ability?  I would have guessed it was triggered, thus OP would have won while it was still on the stack, but I'm a bit rusty at this...

Comment: @DanStaley - you can tell by the wording: "When/Whenever/At [trigger], [event]" are triggered abilities. Replacement effects are commonly phrased using "If [something], [something else] instead", and "~ enters the battlefield with/as ..." though there are several other wordings, too. See rule 614 for the full list.

Comment: Can you quote a source for the match score paragraph? I thought that a draw would be recorded as 0-0-1, so if the previous score for the match was 1-0-0, now the score would be 1-0-1 and the match would continue.